# Best practice way to update a parent document field that is computed from sub collection documents in google cloud firestore

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Here's an abbreviated version of the data model for my firestore collections:

```js
// /posts/{postId}
interface Post {
  id: string;
  lastCommentedAt: Timestamp | null
}

// /posts/{postId}/comments/{commentId}
interface Comment {
  id: string;
  createdAt: Timestamp;
}
```

So I have a collection of posts, and within each post is a subcollection of comments.

I want to do the following:

- When a comment is created, update the `lastCommentedAt` field of the parent Post document with the comment's `createdAt` value
- When a comment is deleted, the parent Post's `lastCommentedAt` field may no longer be valid so we need to get all of the Post's comments and get the most recent comment to update `lastCommentedAt`.

I see a couple ways to do this:

1. In my client code, I can do the above logic inside of functions like `createComment(post, comment)`, and `deleteComment(post, comment)`

   - Especially in the case of deleting it seems like it is not ideal to require the client to fetch all comments for the post and iterate through them just to delete one
   - Would I need to use transactions for this since someone could be deleting a comment at the same time someone was creating a new one?
2. In my cloud functions I could create triggers on `/posts/{postId}/comments/{commentId}` for create and delete and do this logic on the backend

   - Is there risk of race conditions here as well? Again maybe I should use a transaction?

The use case for this `lastCommentedAt` field is that I want to be able to query for posts and sort them by the ones that have recent comments.

---

Edit: possible implementation for `deleteComment` using a batched write. Is it actually safe to do a query for documents before the writes though?

```js
async function deleteComment(post, comment) {
  const batch = writeBatch(firestore);
  const postRef = doc("posts", post.id);
  const commentRef = doc("posts", post.id, "comments", comment.id);
  const commentsCollection = collection("posts", post.id, "comments");

  const recentCommentSnapshot = await getDocs(
    query(
      commentsCollection,
      where("id", "!=", comment.id),
      orderBy("createdAt", "desc"),
      limit(1)
    )
  );

  let lastCommentedAt = null;
  if (recentCommentSnapshot.docs.length > 0) {
    lastCommentedAt = recentCommentSnapshot.docs[0].data().createdAt;
  }

  batch.delete(commentRef);
  batch.update(postRef, { lastCommentedAt });
  await batch.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For adding comments you can use [batched writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) to ensure the comment is added and the parent document is update with current [timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#server_timestamp).

```
const batch = db.batch();

const postDocRef = db.collection('posts').doc('postId');
const commentRef = postDocRef.collection("comments").doc();

batch.update(postDocRef, { lastCommentedAt: FieldValue.serverTimestamp() });

batch.set(commentRef, { createdAt: FieldValue.serverTimestamp() }); 
 
await batch.commit();
```

When deleting comments you might have to query the latest comment using `createdAt` field and then update parent document.

```
const getLastComment = (postId: string) => {
  const postRef = db.collection('posts').doc(postId);
  return await postRef.orderBy('createdAt', 'desc').limit(1).get();
}
```

Comment: Nice, batched writes do seem like exactly what I need when creating comments. For deletes though, won't there be a risk that after I query for the two most recent comments  and then do my business logic those comments might no longer exist / there could be new more recent comments?

Comment: @SpencerWood just to clarify, is `lastUpdatedAt` the timestamp when a post was either added or deleted or just the timestamp of latest comment?

Comment: the field is `lastCommentedAt` and it's the timestamp of the most recent comment for that post (if there is one)

Comment: @SpencerWood ah right, so it batched writes will work for adding comments (and will be current timestamp at all times). When deleting comments, you would update `lastCommentedAt` only when the latest comment is deleted right? Also you cannot run a query within a transaction so you'll have to first delete the comment and then get the new latest comment and update parent doc. Again, you might want to check if the comment deleted was the latest comment and then only update parent doc.

Comment: You can set `limit(1)` just to get latest comment. The reason I had limit as 2 was just in case the document delete was latest then you can get timestamp of new latest comment right there and you can use that to update parent doc.

Comment: I added a possible implementation of deleteComment with a batched write and a query to the original post, curious on your thoughts

Comment: @SpencerWood as i mentioned earlier you cannot run a query in a txn so you'll have to do that. I would add an if statement that says `if (recentComments[0].id === commentToDelete.id)`, then only update lastCommentedAt if that makes sense.